# how to use the auto complete of google map without the map but the auto suggest of places only?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, google-maps

I have a input form whereby users should be able to see a suggestion of places that is related to the word he/she typed. the solution i found by googling is using the google map autocomplete. But the problem is, I don't need the map at all. All I want is the function that gives suggestion when user types something in my own input box. Can someone help pinpoint which part of this googlemap code should I use only to get what I need ?

```
<script>
  // This example requires the Places library. Include the libraries=places
  // parameter when you first load the API. For example:
  // <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places">

  function initMap() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      center: {lat: -33.8688, lng: 151.2195},
      zoom: 13
    });
    var card = document.getElementById('pac-card');
    var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');
    var types = document.getElementById('type-selector');
    var strictBounds = document.getElementById('strict-bounds-selector');

    map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT].push(card);

    var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);

    // Bind the map's bounds (viewport) property to the autocomplete object,
    // so that the autocomplete requests use the current map bounds for the
    // bounds option in the request.
    autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    var infowindowContent = document.getElementById('infowindow-content');
    infowindow.setContent(infowindowContent);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: map,
      anchorPoint: new google.maps.Point(0, -29)
    });

    autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function() {
      infowindow.close();
      marker.setVisible(false);
      var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
      if (!place.geometry) {
        // User entered the name of a Place that was not suggested and
        // pressed the Enter key, or the Place Details request failed.
        window.alert("No details available for input: '" + place.name + "'");
        return;
      }

      // If the place has a geometry, then present it on a map.
      if (place.geometry.viewport) {
        map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
      } else {
        map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
        map.setZoom(17);  // Why 17? Because it looks good.
      }
      marker.setPosition(place.geometry.location);
      marker.setVisible(true);

      var address = '';
      if (place.address_components) {
        address = [
          (place.address_components[0] && place.address_components[0].short_name || ''),
          (place.address_components[1] && place.address_components[1].short_name || ''),
          (place.address_components[2] && place.address_components[2].short_name || '')
        ].join(' ');
      }

      infowindowContent.children['place-icon'].src = place.icon;
      infowindowContent.children['place-name'].textContent = place.name;
      infowindowContent.children['place-address'].textContent = address;
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
    });

    // Sets a listener on a radio button to change the filter type on Places
    // Autocomplete.
    function setupClickListener(id, types) {
      var radioButton = document.getElementById(id);
      radioButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
        autocomplete.setTypes(types);
      });
    }

    setupClickListener('changetype-all', []);
    setupClickListener('changetype-address', ['address']);
    setupClickListener('changetype-establishment', ['establishment']);
    setupClickListener('changetype-geocode', ['geocode']);

    document.getElementById('use-strict-bounds')
        .addEventListener('click', function() {
          console.log('Checkbox clicked! New state=' + this.checked);
          autocomplete.setOptions({strictBounds: this.checked});
        });
  }
</script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places&callback=initMap"
    async defer></script>
```

that code snippet above is from [this url](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete) below:

```
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This example from the documentation doesn't include a map:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform

Relavant code:

```
function initAutocomplete() {
  // Create the autocomplete object, restricting the search to geographical
  // location types.
  autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
      /** @type {!HTMLInputElement} */(document.getElementById('autocomplete')),
      {types: ['geocode']});
}
```

**code snippet:**

```html
<script>
  function initAutocomplete() {
    // Create the autocomplete object, restricting the search to geographical
    // location types.
    autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
      /** @type {!HTMLInputElement} */
      (document.getElementById('autocomplete')), {
        types: ['geocode']
      });

  }
</script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete" async defer></script>
<input id="autocomplete" placeholder="Enter your address" type="text" />
```